# How to call function when readLine is received

Tags: c#, serial-port, readline

My program needs to receive strings through the serialport. 
Problem is that the program is stuck on ReadLine when there's no input. 
Is there a way to call the function startReading when a line is read by SP.ReadLine?

```
void GetInput()
{
        SerialPort SP = new SerialPort();
        SP.PortName = "COM3";
        SP.Open();
        string Line = string.Empty;
        While(Line == "")
         {
                    Line = SP.ReadLine();
                    Application.DoEvents();
         }
          StartReading();
}

void StartReading()
{
}
```

Comment: So you want the `StartReading` method to execute in parallel with the `while` loop?

Comment: just look at the provided events http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived.aspx and research asynchronous reading from streams in c#/.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void GetInput()
    {
        SerialPort SP = new SerialPort();
        SP.PortName = "COM3";
        SP.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SP_DataReceived);
        SP.Open();
    }

    private void SP_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort)sender;
        string line = serialPort.ReadLine();
        StartReading();
    }

    private void StartReading()
    {
    }
```